# Bluetooth stopped working after upgrade to fedora 32

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, drivers, bluetooth, firmware

I have Fedora 32 that I've updated recently. I've had power outage, so I need to power down the laptop and after I've booted it again the bluetooth stopped working (I'm not sure if I've updated something before the shutdown).

This is what linux say:

```
$ uname -a
Linux jcubic 5.6.16-300.fc32.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 4 18:08:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    2.683570] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.683589] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.683592] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.683593] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.683595] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.693267] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin failed with error -2
[    2.693269] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to request rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin (-2)
[    8.209092] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.209093] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.209095] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

$ locate rampatch_usb_00000302.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/qca/rampatch_usb_00000302.bin

$ lsmod | grep -i bluetooth
bluetooth             643072  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  8 bluetooth,dell_laptop,cfg80211

$ LC_ALL=C rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked

$ hciconfig up 
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 commands:0 errors:0

$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-06-12 19:21:41 CEST; 55min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 879 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18735)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─879 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

cze 12 19:21:41 jcubic systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
cze 12 19:21:41 jcubic bluetoothd[879]: Bluetooth daemon 5.54
cze 12 19:21:41 jcubic systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
cze 12 19:21:41 jcubic bluetoothd[879]: Starting SDP server
cze 12 19:21:41 jcubic bluetoothd[879]: Bluetooth management interface 1.15 initialized
```

I have no idea what happen, can it be hardware failure? I have only one kernel for Fedora 32 in grub. I've recently have sometimes issue with weird noise from my laptop, maybe it's a fan for the CPU.

EDIT:

I was not able to find any solution so I've cloned mirror of Linux repo from GitHub and it seems that error -2 because file or directory was not found:

```
 #define    ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
```

**EDIT:**

I've just booted live DVD of Xubuntu 20.04 and bluetooth is working, I'm reporting the as a bug to Fedora.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is my findings and steps I did, I've reported the issue to [Fedora bug tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1846757) they suggested to remove and add kernel module:

```
# modprobe -r btusb
# modprobe btusb
```

it kind of worked the error in dmesg was gone, The bluetooth indicator disappeared (not sure how to restart it) but I was able to use `bluetoothctl`, I was able to scan for devices, but pairing was not working. My GNU/Linux System attempted to connect, but then disconnecting with error:

> Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed

After some struggle I've solved the issue. After enabling debug logs in bluez it showed this error:

> connect error: Permission denied (13)

so the solution was to remove and pair again the device:

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# devices
...
Device 04:FE:A1:57:6D:F3 JBL Flip 4
[bluetooth]# remove 04:FE:A1:57:6D:F3
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# pair 04:FE:A1:57:6D:F3
[bluetooth]# connect 04:FE:A1:57:6D:F3
```

**NOTE:**  this is just workaround before the bug is fixed in Fedora. This is also not permanent solution, after fix it can happen again.

**NOTE2:** I have this issue multiple times, maybe it's a bug in the Kernel, after second time I didn't need to remove the device in bluetoothctl. Removing and adding kernel module was enough.